# Having trouble changing parent class variables in MineSweeper

Tags: java

I have three variables within the parent class that alter the difficulty of the game.

```
public class MineSweeper implements ActionListener{
    int gridlength = 20;
    int gridheight = 20;    
    int numMines = 30;
```

When the user clicks new game, a prompt should appear which allows the user to change the difficulty. It does run the following prompts, but it always reverts to the values above. How can I change the values for the new game?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == newGame){
        String gridl = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(subframe, "Please enter in the amount of columns.");
        gridlength = Integer.parseInt(gridl);
        String gridh = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(subframe, "Please enter in the amount of rows.");
        gridheight = Integer.parseInt(gridh);
        String amountOfMines = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(subframe, "Please enter in the amount of mines.");   
        numMines = Integer.parseInt(amountOfMines);
        new MineSweeper();
```

Comment: You're instantiating an entirely different `MineSweeper` with brand new default values; that's the problem

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use recursion? Wouldn't it be better to give the GUI a `reset()` method that you can call after changing the fields above, and then allow it to reset all its values and re-draw its GUI?

Comment: Sorry guys!! It just dawned on me. I had to change the variables in the parent class to static int numMines.... and in the newgame method, change the variable declaration to MineSweeper.numMines = ....

Comment: No, don't make the variable static as that is a very non-OOP solution, one that can make your program difficult to improve later, and if I were your instructor, I'd knock down your grade for this as it is bad coding technique. Instead change the field and re-build the grid.